# Prioritize conda pip over pip

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, plotly, conda

I installed `pip` and installed `python` for terminal use for a previous course. The course I am currently in, specified I install `Anaconda`. I installed `Anaconda` and when using `JupyterLab` for `python` and `plotly`, I installed the `plotly-geo` package. It says it is not installed though and when I try to install again it says it is installed.

Is it because I installed pip python prior? How would I remove all of pip and reinstall it for Anaconda?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Desktop/Data_Visualization/p3_source/p3.py", line 25, in <module>
    exponent_format=True,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/figure_factory/_county_choropleth.py", line 622, in create_choropleth
    """
ValueError: 
The create_choropleth figure factory requires the plotly-geo package.
Install using pip with:
$ pip install plotly-geo
Or, install using conda with
$ conda install -c plotly plotly-geo
```

Comment: Are you not using the Python installation from one of the Conda environments?

Answer (score 0):

The path of the site packages from your error suggests that you are executing your script with the non-anaconda version of python. I would suggest to uninstall it and only keep your anaconda distribution, as you can just create virtual environments should you need another python version